# Is there a CSS media query to change devicePixelRatio?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, pixel, display

Is there a CSS media query that I can use to set `devicePixelRatio` at 1 when a browser open my web page?

I'm using a screen resolution of 1920x1080 with a 125% scale on display (OS is Windows 10). If I open the website I'm working on, everything is obviously bigger and scroll bars appear.

Is there a media query I can write in CSS in order to change `devicePixelRatio` to 1 if it's greater than that value?

Comment: I think it will work according to your media query, when you `+` the size of window, it is just the size `width` of window, what you can do here like when you do `+` screen then check window `width` (a certain point) for same make media queries accordingly. Hope this will help.

Comment: One thing if you want same behavior on `+` you should use `vw` and `vh` for width and height. It will keep the things same.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the value of your devices Pixel Ratio, this is a fixed value that depends on your screen and your device. You can only read it and react to it.

Comment: Ok, so how can I read it and react to it, for example by changing the zoom? Is it possible to do something like this?